# What is the mechanism of monofunctional glycosylase catalysis?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, biochemistry

I am learning about base excision repair mechanisms. I understand the main idea how glycosylases are working, but I am trying to understand this in much more detail. I found a paper where they have written:

> Monofunctional glycosylases catalyze the single-step displacement of damaged base via attack of an activated water molecule on c1' of the substrate

I am not sure what an "activated water molecule" is, how, for example, an aspartate residue is making a water molecule 'activated', and how this "activated water molecule" is removing the damaged base (hydrolysis N-glycosyl bond).

Source:
[J Christopher Fromme, Anirban Banerjee, Gregory L Verdine: DNA glycosylase recognition and catalysis.](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0959440X04000041)

Comment: This is a duplicate of a question on biology SE: http://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19667/question-about-monofunctional-glycosylases/19703#19703

Comment: ***Cross-Posting is strongly discouraged!*** @canadianer I flagged it for the moderators - but you can also do this yourself, the next time you see something like this.

Comment: I was going to flag it as a duplicate but it said that the duplicate post must be on chemistry SE so I wasn't sure if it was allowed or not.

Comment: This already has an excellent answer on Bio.SE.  As noted above, please do not cross-post because it results in the duplication of efforts and is unfair to those who have put in a lot of time to answer on the other site.